# Derivative of inverse function as matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives

Assumed I have my function $f(x)$ discretized on a vector $\vec{f}$ using the vector $\vec{r}$ and the spacing $dr$, and I want to calculate the first derivative from it, I can multiply it by a band matrix with $-\frac{2}{dh}$ on the main diagonal and $\frac{1}{dh}$ on the first subdiagonals, called $A$. Thus I can write the operation as 
$$\frac{d}{dr} f(\vec{r})=A\cdot\vec{f}$$
Now I want to do the same, but for $\frac{1}{f}$ when only $\vec{f}$ is given (assumed that $\frac{1}{f}$ exists over the whole definition range). Is there such a transformation matrix $B$ that I can write
$$\frac{d}{dr}\frac{1}{f(\vec{r})}=B\cdot\vec{f}$$?

In order to make it easier, the matrix $B$ can be split up into two matrices, $$B=C\cdot D$$ with
$$\frac{1}{\vec{f}}=D\cdot\vec{f}$$
and 
$$\frac{d}{dr}\frac{1}{\vec{f}}=C\cdot D\cdot\vec{f}$$
Matrix $C$ is known, but my problem is to find matrix $D$. Is there such a matrix?